# Decomposition of triangle-free bridgeless planar cubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

**Question:**
is it true that every triangle-free connected bridgeless planar cubic graph can be decomposed into a vertex-disjoint cycle cover and a *single* maximal matching of the edges that are adjacent to a pair of vertices from a different pair of the cycles of the cover and if not, what are counter examples?

Comment: Is $K_4$ a counterexample?

Comment: @Bullet51 yes it is a counterexample that I forgot to rule out.